Comparing the solutions of two "close" SDEs
Let $X= (X_t)_{t\geq 0}$ and $Y= (Y_t)_{t\geq0}$ respectively be the solutions of the SDEs:
$$ dX_t = b(X_t)dt + \sigma(X_t)dB_t, \quad X_0 = y$$
and
$$ dY_t = b'(Y_t)dt + \sigma'(Y_t)dB_t, \quad Y_0 =y$$
where we have used the same Brownian motion (on $\mathbb R$) in both equations and the two processes start from the same point $y$.
Suppose that I know $b'$ is "close" to $b$ and $\sigma'$ is "close" to $\sigma$, can we compare. Here, "close" doesn't have a precise meaning but I imagine something like
$$ |b(x)-b'(x)| + |\sigma(x) -\sigma'(x)| \leq g(x), \quad \forall x \in \mathbb R, $$
for some function $g$, where $g$ could be constant (so that $\| b-b' \|_\infty \leq C)$, integrable or compactly supported, etc. What is the general approach to bound the distance $|X_t -Y_t|$ or maybe the distance of the law of $X_t$ and $Y_t$?
From this question, I want to understand better how "close" (in any sense) $X$ and $Y$ are? Any reference/papers/books that address this question will help me a lot! Thank you in advance!
